# How to store maths quiz scores for a class on a notepad file using python?

Tags: python, storage

I get an error message, my program works up until the last bit where it says the persons score but then i get an error message and the program doesnt store the persons score for their class in the notepad document i have made. I have added the code below so please help me with this and suggest how i can improve my code to not receive this error message.

```py
import random
def questions():
    name=input("What is your name: ")
    print("Hello there",name,"! Please answer 10 random maths questions for this test!")
    Class=input("Which class are you in?")

    choice = random.choice("+-x")
    finish = False
    questionnumber = 0
    correctquestions = 0

    while finish == False:
        choice = random.choice("+-x")
        if questionnumber < 10 | questionnumber >= 0:
            number1 = random.randrange(1,10)
            number2 = random.randrange(1,10)
            print((number1),(choice),(number2))
            answer=int(input("What is the answer?"))
            questionnumber = questionnumber + 1

            if choice==("+"):
                realanswer = number1+number2
                if answer==realanswer:
                    print("That's the correct answer")
                    correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong answer, the answer was",realanswer,"!")

            if choice==("x"):
                realanswer = number1*number2
                if answer==realanswer:
                    print("That's the correct answer")
                    correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong answer, the answer was",realanswer,"!")

            elif choice==("-"):
                realanswer = number1-number2

                if answer==realanswer:
                    print("That's the correct answer")
                    correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong answer, the answer was",realanswer,"!")
        else:
            finish = True
    else:
            print("Good job",name,"! You have finished the quiz")
            print("You scored " + str(correctquestions) + "/10 questions.")
            if ClassOfStudent==1:
                Class=open('N:Class 1 Score.txt','a')
    Class.write(name)
    Class.write(str(correctquestions))
    Class.close()
    if ClassOfStudent==2:
        Class=open('N:Class 2 Score.txt','a')
    Class.write(name)
    Class.write(str(correctquestions))
    Class.close()
    if ClassOfStudent==3:
        Class=open('N:Class 3 Score.txt','a')
    Class.write(name)
    Class.write(str(correctquestions))
    Class.close()
questions()
```

Comment: Note that you're using the name `Class` for two totally different things, which will only confuse the matter. Also, **what error message?!** Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what's `ClassofStudent`? I suppose you want to write `ClassofStudent=input("Which class are you in?")`!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
Class=open('N:Class 1 Score.txt','a')
```

The `:` character is not a valid file name. If you have a `N` drive on your computer, then use the following:

```
Class=open(r'N:\Class 1 Score.txt','a')
```

Of course, make sure the user account that is executing the script has access to write to files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

The `error` is `Class=input("Which class are you in?").` It needs to be `Class=int(input("Which class are you in?")).`